# Минимум из списка на R

Tags: list, r, min

Есть два списка именно:

```
a <- list(0, 1, 1, 0, 1)
b <- list(5.35, -14, 21, -70, 5)
```

Как мне в одну строку получить индекс самого маленького элемента из b, только среди тех индексов у которых в a на этих же позициях стоят единицы. Например в данном случае минимальный элемент в b будет -14

Answer (score 2):

например, так (пробелы вставлены лишь для лучшего восприятия, их в данном случае можно убрать все до одного):

```
min( unlist( b )[ unlist( a ) == 1 ] )
```

где:

- `unlist(список)` — преобразование списка в вектор (векторами гораздо проще манипулировать)
- `вектор == значение` — результатом будет замена элементов вектора, равных указанному значению, на `T` (true, истина), остальных — на `F` (false, ложь)
- `вектор[вектор_индексов]` — фильтрация вектора: если энный элемент в вектор_индексов — ложь, то энный элемент вектора пропускается
- `min(вектор)` — получение минимального значения вектора.

---

ах, да, требуется не значение, а индекс. для этого вместо функции `min()` можно воспользоваться функцией `which.min()`.

Comment: Ооо, спасибо огромное, судя по всему можно сократить на min(unlist(b)[unlist(a) == 1]), а индекс получить посредством which

Comment: я дополнил ответ.